# Unable to setup Hadoop single node on Win7

Tags: windows, hadoop

I am trying to setup Hadoop to run on a single node on windows as per [this guide](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hadoop2OnWindows).

When I get to this part:

```
%HADOOP_PREFIX%\bin\hdfs namenode -format
```

I get this error:

```
C:\deploy\etc\hadoop>%HADOOP_PREFIX%\bin\hdfs namenode -format
15/07/29 14:51:11 ERROR util.Shell: Failed to locate the winutils binary in the
hadoop binary path
java.io.IOException: Could not locate executable C:\deploy\bin\winutils.exe in the Hadoop binaries.
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getQualifiedBinPath(Shell.java:355)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getWinUtilsPath(Shell.java:370)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.<clinit>(Shell.java:363)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.StringUtils.<clinit>(StringUtils.java:78)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:14
72)
```

What is the winutils.exe? I don't see it as part of the hadoop tar file :(